# page width for screen resolution 1024+

Tags: scrollbar, scroll

I'm facing an age old question of html page width - have decided graphics have more "je nai say quo" with fixed than percentage and so to go with a central column of 1000px (with 1024 screen res in mind)

with graphics in mind, i also want left and right of the central column some nice bordering options - increasing the total width potentially by any amount.

so my question is whether its possible to open up a page on a 1024 screen res and have it auto scroll so the middle column shows (regardless of the left border).

today - on the site http://www.delightwebdesign.co.uk the left invisible border - only visible with firebug (intended for graphics) at the moment pushes the middle column rightwards and partly out of view, I'd essentially like the top left of a low res browser to start with the top left of the middle column?

thanks and all input much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen for the `load` event and then scroll to the position of your middle column (either get the position by JS, or a pre-set position).

Example (jQuery used for brevity):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.scrollTo(200,0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input - using html / css I've come halfway to a good solution.. an outside wrapper set to 100% width removes all horizontal scroll bars, a wrapper in the outside wrapper with central page width (1000px) and set to margin auto appears in the middle of the window (or fills it) on all screen resolutions, an inner wrapper set to, for example 1400px width with left:200px allows a margin on each side, only visible on higher resolutions.

Comment: @Will Fairfield: That's clever! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: thanks personally I thought it quite a far out solution although quite inspired too! so I'm happy its appreciated!! I've written as an answer the remainder of the question which is how to account for any screen res < 1000px, I know its possible but my JavaScript syntax needs a bit of tweaking - or perhaps how to call this function on load